# Compare two lists to determine new, edited, and removed entries in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to compare two lists to determine which entries from the second list are new, edited, or removed. I have the following code that takes a very long time to run on large lists. The use case here is to compare a list of data from an Api at start, and then fetch new data and determine changes compared to our original list.

```
class Geofence {
  final String createdAt;
  final String lastModified;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String id;
  final List<Coordinates> coordinateList;
  final double area;
  final String entranceDescription;
  final bool enabled;

  Geofence({
    @required this.createdAt,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.coordinateList,
    @required this.enabled,
    this.description,
    this.area,
    this.lastModified,
    this.entranceDescription,
  })  : assert(createdAt != null),
        assert(name != null),
        assert(id != null),
        assert(coordinateList != null),
        assert(enabled != null);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Geofence &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          id == other.id &&
          name == other.name &&
          enabled == other.enabled &&
          lastModified == other.lastModified &&
          description == other.description &&
          coordinateList == other.coordinateList &&
          area == other.area &&
          entranceDescription == other.entranceDescription &&
          enabled == other.enabled;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}


 // _previousGeofences = <Geofence>[ // multiple items returned from Api ]
 // _fetchedGeofences = <Geofence>[ // multiple items returned from Api ]

if (_previousGeofences.isNotEmpty && _fetchedGeofences.isNotEmpty) {
      final newItems = <bool>[],
          editedItems = <bool>[],
          removedItems = <bool>[];

      // Determine new items
      for (final map in _fetchedGeofences) {
        var foundItems =
            _previousGeofences.any((Geofence item) => item.id == map.id);

        if (!foundItems) {
          newItems.add(foundItems);
        }
      }

      // Determine removed items
      for (final map in _previousGeofences) {
        final foundItems =
            _fetchedGeofences.any((Geofence item) => item.id == map.id);

        if (!foundItems) {
          removedItems.add(foundItems);
        }
      }

      // Determine edited items
      for (final map in _previousGeofences) {
        final foundItems =
            _fetchedGeofences.any((Geofence item) => item == map);

        if (!foundItems) {
          editedItems.add(foundItems);
        }
      }
```

I'm trying to learn what shortcuts in Dart I can utilize to help speed this up and be of better quality.

Comment: Your approach is O(n^2).  Do you care about order?  If not, then using two [`Set`s](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set-class.html) would allow you to compute the [differences](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set/difference.html) in O(n) time.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "edited" since you seem to just be comparing objects for identity.

Comment: "edited" would mean that *any property of the class* has changed.

Comment: I'm guessing that edited means that the *id* is the same, but the properties of the objects are not all equal. The use of `id` in the `hashCode`  is not compatible with `==`, which is a problem. You have two notions of being "equal": Having the same ID (represents the same thing, but may be different objects) and being unchanged (same ID and same other properties). Choose *one* of those for `==` and let hashCode be compatible. Then consider having the other equality as a method too, if you really need both.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make some assumptions:

- Each list can contain at most one object with each `id` value.
- An "edited" object in the new list is an object with the same ID
  as an object in the original list, but with different property values.
- An "unchanged" object is a value with the same ID and equal other properties.
- A new object is one in the new list with an ID not in the original list.
- A deleted object is one in the original list with an ID that is not in the new list.

That suggests to me that you should change equality to be ID based and have another method to compare for changes:

```dart
class Geofence {
  final String createdAt;
  final String? lastModified;
  final String name;
  final String? description;
  final String id;
  final List<Coordinates> coordinateList;
  final double? area;
  final String? entranceDescription;
  final bool enabled;

  Geofence({
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
    required this.coordinateList,
    required this.enabled,
    this.description,
    this.area,
    this.lastModified,
    this.entranceDescription,
  });

  /// Whether two objects have the same ID and have equal values
  /// for each property.
  bool isUnchanged(Geofence other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          id == other.id &&
          name == other.name &&
          enabled == other.enabled &&
          lastModified == other.lastModified &&
          description == other.description &&
          coordinateList == other.coordinateList &&
          area == other.area &&
          entranceDescription == other.entranceDescription &&
          enabled == other.enabled;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) || other is Geofence && id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

With that, you can do efficient lookup in a hash-table based on ID.

I'd do something like:

```dart
  List<Geofence> modified = [];
  List<Geofence> removed = [];
  List<Geofence> added = [];
  List<Geofence> unmodified = [];
   
  Set<Geofence> original = {..._previousGeofences};
  for (var fence in _fecthedGeofences) {
    var o = original.lookup(fence);
    if (o == null) {
      added.add(fence);
    } else { 
      original.remove(fence);
      if (o.isUnchanged(fence)) {
        unmodified.add(fence);
      } else {
        modified.add(fence);
      }
    }
  }
  removed.addAll(original);
```

After this, each ID occurring in either `_previousGeofences` or `_fetchedGeofences` also occurs in precisely one of the four lists, depending on whether it occurred in one or both, and if both, whether its content has changed.

The shortcuts to use here is:

- Be clear about the underlying assumptions of your model.
- Use a hash-table based lookup instead of linear lookup (and ensure the class supports that).